# Apache error on ubuntu ERROR: Site (SiteName) does not exist

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm facing a problem when I run `sudo a2ensite test.watermaps-eg.com.conf` to add a new site to apache2 it gives me `ERROR: Site test.watermaps-eg.com does not exist!`

**What I tried to do**

Added the file `test.watermaps-eg.com.conf` inside `sites-enabled`.

Added the `apache2` configurations inside the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName https://test.watermaps-eg.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@innoventiq.com
    ServerName test.watermaps-eg.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/static>
    Require all granted
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/kml_files>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/water_maps>
    Require all granted
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess test_water_maps_django python-path=/home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django python-home=/home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup test_water_maps_django
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/test_water_maps_django/water_maps/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran the command `sudo a2ensite test.watermaps-eg.com.conf` and it returns the mentioned above error.

Comment: Did you try it in `sites-available`? Typically it's `a2ensite` that creates the link from there to `sites-enabled`. However, this question is not quite programming related (see [help/on-topic]), I consider it off-topic on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add the conf (test.watermaps-eg.com.conf) file inside /etc/apache2/**site-available**
before running the command

```
sudo a2ensite test.watermaps-eg.com
```